# How do I measure the area of a labeled segment?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I did image thresholding and use label2rgb() to get my image to show different parts in different colors. How do I use Matlab to calculate the area of each different color? Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it just a sum of the pixels in a specific channel? Could you provide a demo image and the result you're supposed to get? (if you don't have one, please generate a small image and analyze it by hand)

Answer (score 1):

Before using the command label2rgb() i suggest you to use regionprops(I,'Area') and get the area for each label.